# Supervisor had an article retracted (I am not a co-author). Will this affect my career?

Tags: retraction

An old research article of my PhD supervisor with his previous student who worked in  cancer is retracted due to similarity in images. My supervisor was the corresponding author. I was not a co-author. If my supervisor suffers reputational damage, how would this affect my own career? Can there be difficulties publishing my own work with my supervisor, given that they had a paper retracted before?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to make a couple of edits to emphasize what I think you're worrying about, but feel free to add further clarifications or evert the changes if they're misleading. I don't think more details about the alleged misconduct are needed, but further spelling out your concerns could be helpful. Either way, it seems a reasonable question to ask, so I've voted to re-open.

Comment: Was the "similarity of images" a plagiarism issue (stealing ideas no attribution) or a copyright issue (over copying with attribution)?

Comment: @Buffy I assumed it was a data manipulation issue, but it would be good if OP clarified that.

Comment: Is "similarity in images" a euphemism for "pretended images of the same biological specimen were images of different samples"? Because if so it's massively problematic that your advisor would characterize it that way 
("similarity of images") and further that you'd repeat that same language...

Answer (score 1):

> If my supervisor suffers reputational damage, how would this affect my own career?

Probably not at all.  "Image similarity" in medical research often means there was fraud.  Most people will not judge you based on your supervisor's former student's behavior.

> Can there be difficulties publishing my own work with my supervisor,
> given that they had a paper retracted before?

Probably not at all.  Publishing decisions should be made on the content of the paper, not the identity of the authors.  To do otherwise would be unethical.

If your supervisor happened to commit grant fraud, that could be a real problem.  Usually scientists who are caught committing grant fraud loose their funding and are banned from getting new funding for a period of time.  Then they cannot pay their PhD students.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has helped me alot. I was really worried when I heard of the misconduct.

Answer (score -1):

It can happen to good people that they make a mistake and have to retract an article. (Somewhere on youtube is a talk by a statistician who points to a retracted article by himself. There was a problem in entering data into a spread sheet.) Voluntary retraction of an article would actually speak to the academic virtue of the retractor. Under such circumstances, you should not expect any disadvantages of publishing with your advisor.

Being a corresponding author does not mean being responsible for everything. If your co-student fabricated research results, then your advisor might not have been in a position to detect this before submission of the article. In this case again, no blemish on your advisor and you should not expect some disadvantage of publishing with your advisor.

If however your advisor was grossly negligent or dishonest, then any of your advisor's publication might draw much more scrutiny (as the academic community in a special field tends to be small and therefore more cognizant of trespasses) and this would be to your disadvantage. However, people will also realize that you were not involved in this incident and that changing advisors can be difficult.

Comment: Hmmm. Actually, every author is responsible for everything. And a supervisor has a special responsibility. But some cases are problematic and others less so, as you say.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. No supervisor will redo experiments / simulations done by a competent graduate student. No supervisor will be redoing field interviews. They will talk with the student about the results and methodology, but supervision will not be watching over a student's shoulder while contributions to the paper are made.  In the case of Schön from Konstanz, the respective institutions judged (with the tacit approval of the communities) that many co-authors were not only innocent, but also not culpable.

Comment: Sorry, but if your name is on the paper as author, you take responsibility for everything in it. If not, then you ain't doin' your job.

Comment: @Buffy: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning here. How would this work, e.g. in interdisciplinary research? For instance, I am a mathematician specialized in functional analysis and I'm currently working with economists on a mathematical problem in trade theory. Of course I care also about the economic background, and they have considerable mathematical background knowledge. But we are using some extremely specialized mathematical tools to analyze trade models which have very extensive economic background. Assume for instance that I write a paragraph about [...]

Comment: [...] how one of the mathematical techniques that we use developed and I happen to severely misrepresent the development of this technique. How could my colleagues from economics take responsibility for this, given that it took me many years to accquire the necessary background knowledge to understand the development of those ideas? Similarly, how could I take responsibility for the economic context to be presented and interpreted correctly throughout the paper? It requires years of experience and high familiarity with the relevant literature to get those things really right.